# Python Sockets Timeout Error 10060 Over the Internet

Tags: python, sockets

I have been following this tutorial to send messages between a Windows (8.1) PC and a Windows VPS: https://www.techwithtim.net/tutorials/socket-programming/

According to the tutorial to make the scripts work over the internet all that is needed is to change the line below to the public IP of the server (which I am running on the PC).

```
SERVER = socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname())
```

Everything works ok when I run the scripts on my local network but when I try to use them remotely I get this error:

```
TimeoutError: [WinError 10060] A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond
```

There isn't much out there on how to solve it but I have tried disabling the firewalls on the PC and VPS. This didn't help.

I then tried changing the IP address in the server script to 0.0.0.0 as some have suggested but this hasn't helped either.

Can anyone see the issue?

Here's the server script:

```
import socket
import threading

HEADER = 64
PORT = 5050
SERVER = "0.0.0.0" #socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname())
ADDR = (SERVER, PORT)
FORMAT = 'utf-8'
DISCONNECT_MESSAGE = "!DISCONNECT"

server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
server.bind(ADDR)


def handle_client(conn, addr):
    print(f"[NEW CONNECTION] {addr} connected.")

    connected = True
    while connected:
        msg_length = conn.recv(HEADER).decode(FORMAT)
        if msg_length:
            msg_length = int(msg_length)
            msg = conn.recv(msg_length).decode(FORMAT)
            if msg == DISCONNECT_MESSAGE:
                connected = False

            print(f"[{addr}] {msg}")
            conn.send("Msg received".encode(FORMAT))

    conn.close()


def start():
    server.listen()
    print(f"[LISTENING] Server is listening on {SERVER}")
    while True:
        conn, addr = server.accept()
        thread = threading.Thread(target=handle_client, args=(conn, addr))
        thread.start()
        print(f"[ACTIVE CONNECTIONS] {threading.activeCount() - 1}")


print("[STARTING] server is starting...")
start()
```

And here's the client script:

```
import socket

HEADER = 64
PORT = 5050
FORMAT = 'utf-8'
DISCONNECT_MESSAGE = "!DISCONNECT"
SERVER = "xxxxxxxxxxxx"
ADDR = (SERVER, PORT)

client = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
client.connect(ADDR)

def send(msg):
    message = msg.encode(FORMAT)
    msg_length = len(message)
    send_length = str(msg_length).encode(FORMAT)
    send_length += b' ' * (HEADER - len(send_length))
    client.send(send_length)
    client.send(message)
    print(client.recv(2048).decode(FORMAT))

send("Hello World!")
input()
send("Hello Everyone!")
input()
send("Hello Tim!")

send(DISCONNECT_MESSAGE)
```

Comment: Just a suggestion: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=WinError+10060. That said, you should provide a [mcve] including the output it produces. The output is missing which is really bad, it should include the full backtrace in case of errors. Your code also requires manual input, which is not a big thing but still something you could resolve with ease.